# Storm worker not starting

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to storm a storm topology but the storm worker refuses to start when I try to run the java  command which invokes the worker process I get the following error:

```
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

I am not able to find what problem is causing this. Has anyone faced similar issue

Edit:
when I runt the worker process with flag -V I get the following error:

```
588 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib
588 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
588 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
588 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Server environment:os.name=Linux
588 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
588 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Server environment:os.version=3.5.0-23-generic
588 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Server environment:user.name=storm
588 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Server environment:user.home=/home/storm
588 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Server environment:user.dir=/home/storm/storm-0.9.0.1
797 [main] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
```

PS: When I run the same topology in local cluster it works fine, only when i deploy in cluster mode it doesnt start.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out the issue. The jar I creted to upload in the storm cluster, was kept in the storm base directory pics. This somehow was creating conflict which was not shown in the log file and actually log file never got created.

Make sure no external jars are present in the base storm folder from where one start storm. Really tricky error no idea why this happens until you just get around it.

Hope the storm guys add this into the logs so that user facing such issue can pinpoint why exactly this is happening.